# Images and Videos missing from phone after system update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, photos, gallery, asus-zenfone-2

I have the [Zenfone 2 ZE551ML 32GB.](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_2_ze551ml-6917.php) After updating to the [latest version](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=60767&extra=page%3D1&mobile=2) I noticed my most recent taken photos and videos are missing, they were all taken on the 15th of december. Even an album called bluetooth which had 1 picture in it is gone. I can't see the photos in any app or even the file manager, can't see them when I plug in the phone on a PC as well. I don't have an SD card on the phone so everything is in the internal storage.

Another weird thing is it says i'm using 6GB out of 25 of my internal storage but highlighting all files and check properties only shows 1.7GB.

Comment: I have no clue for the missing photos problem, but the used space refers to system space, apps space and file space, so that's why files take up only a fraction of it.